# How to add a view on button click without using interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios

I just did it like this

```
 -(IBAction)clickButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {
NSLog(@"Clicked.........");
UIView *showView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:showView];
 }
```

This  action called & There were no any error coming but this view is also not shown.

Comment: try adding [self.view setNeedsLayout] after your addSubview line

Comment: check view is added to parentView or not using - showView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redcolor];

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the view's background color to make sure that it is not actually added without you noticing, also release your view after adding it (if you are not using ARC)

```
-(IBAction)clickButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked.........");
    UIView *showView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    showView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:showView];
    [showView release]; // if not ARC
}
```